# How should i create datacontract for a List of class which contain nested list of classes as properties

Tags: wcf, list, contract

```
  public class GroupItem
   {
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public string ID{get;set;}
   }


   public class MainItem
    {
        public List<GroupItem> Group {get;set;}
        public string Title {get;set;}
        public string Username {get;set;}
    } 


   [ServiceContract]
    public interface MyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<MainItem> GetData(int value);
    }
```

I have a  Interface named MyService.And Its one method returns List.Main Item is a class which contain List.
How should i create Datacontract for this **MainItem** clss

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your example is fine and will automatically serialize correctly.  I recommend attributing your classes with `[DataContract]` and your properties with `[DataMember]` for explicitness.